# Elixir number comparisons with nil

Tags: elixir, comparator

I was hoping someone could shed some light on why numbers (ints, floats, decimals) are allowed to be compared to nil in elixir. Specifically, why `nil` is considered greater than any number - is `nil` then considered infinite? I would expect an error to be raised when comparing numbers to `nil`...

```
# this makes sense I guess
"1" < nil #=> false
"1" > nil #=> true

# but this makes zero sense to me:
1 < nil #=> true 
1 > nil #=> false
```

Are there any good blog posts / documentation around this behavior?

Comment: Let me know if the linked question doesn't answer everything you asked.

Comment: Hi @Dogbert. Thank you! I guess this answers 95% of my question, but I was looking for an explanation "_why_" this is the case more than anything. For example, is the fact that _everything_ in elixir can be compared  important for `pattern matching`...

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/318361/why-does-erlang-provide-built-in-orderingsorting-of-the-basic-data-types includes a quote by the creator of Erlang on the "why". It's not pattern matching; it's because of sorting.

Comment: Note: that nil in Erlang Documentation often means the empty list [], rather than the atom nil.